# ¿Por qué decimos "es total" sobre algo que es muy bueno, especialmente de una forma distinta?

Tags: expresiones, españa

Con frecuencia oigo en España la expresión:

> Ese niño **es total**: siempre que lo veo está haciendo alguna trastada

o

> Ese científico **es total**: tiene unas ideas que siempre consiguen asombrar a sus compañeros.

Es decir, la usamos para denotar que alguien posee una virtud en abundancia: el ser un trasto, ser inteligente o creativo, etc.

¿Por qué ese uso? ¿Acaso usa [*total*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=aA3yF5I) como cúmulo de todo?

Comment: No me suena como una expresión de uso cotidiano. Si pienso en la expresión en voz alta me suena con el típico acento pijo exagerado de las películas :-). No tengo ni idea de su origen, pero puede que sea una contracción de "ese niño es totalmente un trasto" o "ese científico es totalmente un genio" (significando lo mismo que "es un completo genio").

Comment: @fedorqui: La canción "No controles" del grupo musical _Mecano_ no para de repetir el "**es total**" refiriéndose a su forma de vestir, de pensar, bailar y mirar, siempre seguido de un "**y a todos les encanta**" lo que sugiere un significado ligeramente diferente.

Comment: @user13560 exacto, de ahí me suena la expresión, de la movida madrileña. ¿Sigue siendo de uso cotidiano en algún lugar de España?

Comment: @user13560 Sí, eso también encaja con lo que yo entiendo por "es total": alguien con cualidades destacadas que provocan admiración. En este caso, a la forma de ser, vestir, etc.

Comment: @user13560:  te equivocas:  Fue "Flans", no "Mecano".

Comment: @Paul: Posiblemente tengas razón, pero me he basado en que según Wikipedia fue compuesta por **Mecano** para **Ole-ole** en 1983 y años después versionada por **Flans**. https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_controles_(canci%C3%B3n). La verdad es que como no es de mi época, no estoy muy puesto, y me he fiado de Wikipedia ..

Comment: En efecto, por toda España se usaba bastante en los años 80, pero creo que hoy día este uso ha quedado anticuado.

Answer (score 2):

El uso de *es total* es bastante regional en España (¿solamente en Castilla-León y Madrid?) y no se usa de forma amplia aunque sí es nacionalmente reconocido.
Pienso que *es total* se usa como un tipo de forma abreviada y coloquial del adverbio de cantidad o grado *totalmente*. De forma:

> *Ese niño es total* -> *Ese niño es (totalmente) (inteligente, travieso, guapo)*

También me recuerda al uso de *es lo más*, como por ejemplo:

> *Ese niño es lo más* -> *Ese niño (es lo más) (gracioso) (que he visto en mi vida)*

Comment: En Cataluña también se usa.